# How do PDF coordinates work?

Tags: ruby, oracle, pdf, pdf-generation, coordinates

I am trying to convert an ORACLE FAP file (yeah, I know, "fap"...hehe) into a PDF but have run into a snag. Here is what I have done:

1. Found the Documentation http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14902_01/fap_nafile_formats.pdf
2. Figured out the upi to PDF unit conversion is .03
3. Parsed all of the Text (T) objects in a file to start off with.
4. Made sure to adjust for the bottom-left origin PDF uses by using 792(height of PDF) - top-coordinate.

When I try to render the form using Prawn (http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) in Ruby, however, the text is offset all over the document so that most words over-take others. I have played with the unit conversion and tried changing around the coordinates to see if maybe the anchor points in PDF were not at the top-left (for elements) and I still can't get it.

Any thoughts?

[image: Output]

Comment: Alright, I added one. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried reducing the font-size. It actually gets the font-size from the original file, but it still over-laps.

Comment: The thing is this format is made in such a rediculous way that almost every word is a seperate object. For example in "hello, I am bob." it would be ({x,y,"hello"},{x,y,", I"},{x,y,"am"},{x,y,"bob."}) -__-

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've basically got the co-ordinate system worked out. The text characteristics (kerning, font size, character spacing, etc) are probably just a little different.

Are you using the `draw_text()` method?

Try reducing the font size and character space like so:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.character_spacing(0.2) do
  pdf.draw_text "James", :at => [100, 100], :size => 10
end
```

If you're using the `text()` method it should be even easier

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text("James", :size => 10, :character_spacing => 0.2)
```